# Magento: Can I change the discount on an order that is payed for?

Tags: magento, discount

We are developing this Magento site where we need to be able to add discounts on a order after the order is payed for (order has a invoice). Is this possible?

All is done in the backend.

This is our scenario:
1. Backend user adds order.
2. Order is payed for.
3. Invoice is created.
4. We programmatically add a new product to the order.
5. Magento creates a new invoice for the new product, with the extra costs.

On step 4 we would also like to re-calculate the allready given discounts, or replace the existing discount with a new one. Because we also work with percentage discounts it needs to be recalculated on the order.

Comment: Whenever you edit an order, Magento will cancel the current one and create a new one.  Since these are already complete, you would have to refund the entire order then create a new one and charge again.  You're probably better off creating a separate order for the one item you're adding.  You'll need a CIM as well.

Comment: You can edit and order but a new on will be created and the current one will be cancelled. You can then apply discounts using previusly made coupon codes, but that's about as far the default config will get you.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with the above comments, you would have to cancel the order, and start again.
alternatively, create another order with just the price difference.
magento does not make this easy.